# MySQL Upgrade query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, upgrade, percona-server

I have 5.5.44-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) running in one of my RHEL 6.4 server. I need to upgrade the server to Percona Server-5.6.29-76.2. How to go about the upgrade? Should I completely remove the MySQL 5.5 binaries and then proceed with fresh installation of Percona? If not, how to proceed for the same? I have some 5-6 databases running on the instance with sizes less than 1GB.

Comment: Install on top of 5.5.  Be sure to run `mysql_upgrade` as one of the steps.

Comment: Will there be any dependencies on databases which might not import into higher versions? Syntax errors?

Comment: Prepare a good recoverable backup before changing anything.